# Integrability of a piecewise function

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Suppose that $g:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a Riemann integrable function and define $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ as follows
$$ x \mapsto  \begin{cases} g(x) ,  x \neq \frac{1}{n}, n \in \mathbb{N}\\
      n^{2}  , x = \frac{1}{n}, n \in \mathbb{N} \end{cases} $$ My question is $f$ Riemann integrable? I suspect that it is since $f(x)=g(x)$ up to a measure $0$ set, but I'm struggling to prove that $f$ is integrable using the definition of integrability. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am pretty sure it depends on whether you mean Lebesgue integrable or Riemann integrable

Comment: Agree that it matters which kind of integrability you mean, but also want to ask if you really need/want to use the definition of integrability. There are some good and powerful theorems that can make the question much easier.

Comment: What's $n$ in the definition of $f$? Is it fixed, or do you change $g$ at every point in $\{1,\frac12,\frac13,\ldots\}$?

Comment: if $x=\frac{1}{n}$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$ then $f(x) = n^{2}$, if not, then $f(x)=g(x)$

Comment: It is unbounded so it is not Riemann integrable. But it is Lebesgue integrable since its discontinuities form a set of measure zero.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

You just need to prove that the function $ h = f-g$ is integrable at $ [0,1]$.

but

$$h(x)= 0 \text{ if } \;\; x\ne \frac 1n$$
and
$$h(\frac 1n)=n^2-g(\frac 1n)$$

For given small $ \epsilon >0 $ and $ n >\frac{1}{\epsilon}$, use the fact that $h$ is integrable at $[\epsilon,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

In lebesgue one point doesn't change the integrability of the function so if G is integrable also F will be untill the discontinuities are in a measure 0 sets. You can use some dominate convergence to prove it. With definition I think you just don't have to care about the discontinuity point.